# Parse.com Android Facebook Log in suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm using Facebook log in to create accounts on my parse DB. Today it stopped working. I tried to create new accounts with older versions of my app an it's still giving my this:

```
W/ParseLoginFragment﹕ Facebook login failed, exception: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: custom service is not a supported service.
```

It worked fine for more than 2 months. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a small bug in facebook resp. the Parse SDK. I also had the problem and mentioned it in the Parse Framework: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/parse-developers/AipY_BZofzk. Should be fixed now :) At least in iOS it works again.

Comment: Yes! I just got an e-mail from the Parse team saying that it's been fixed :)